# Describing a numbering system that counts from x at the y position in an index

Tags: arrays, indexing, data-structures, computer-science, number-theory

From a theoretical perspective, I'm interested in learning how one would correctly describe a numbering system that starts counting from x at the y position in an index.

This came up when our team recently created a task list using a spreadsheet. Items are referred to by their line item; for example, the item on the third line is Item #3. However, the spreadsheet also has a header row, somewhat like this:

```
 1      TASK                    DESCRIPTION
 2      eat cheese              gouda is preferable here
 3      look around you         just... look around you
 4      rickroll                never gonna give you up
 5      spoon                   you spoony bard!
```

The counting and indexing system has these properties:

- indexing begins at 1
- the first item in the index begins at 2
- the nth item is therefore at the n-1 position

This is a simple enough system to understand at a practical level; but, how would one model it on an abstract level, and what are the correct terms to do so?

Comment: The difference between the row number and the corresponding item number would usually be called an "offset".

Comment: Indexing is your own construct. It is simply a mapping. In computer science, we assign the first element of an array (or sequence) the index 0, the second element the index 1, ..., or the `n`th element the index `n - 1`. This is just one of many examples of using indexing. You can do all sorts of reindexing / creating your own mappings.

Comment: By the way, I saw your meta post and I would encourage you to post an answer if you found one. I would be interested in seeing what you have gathered.

Comment: I appreciate that @oda! This isn't one of the questions that has what I consider to be a complete answer (yet); however, I'll take up your suggestion to close out the others as soon as I have time.